# Chrome data compression cause an Ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, google-chrome, gzip

chrome data compression enable cause an Ajax error .

When I have enable chrome data compression I am getting an error on my ajax function.
It is important because mobile chrome installed as default  with data compression enable.

Ajax error function arguments :

```
status=0 ,responseText="" readyState=0
```

Chrome Console :

```
GET http://example.com/GetData.ashx?_=1413205947410 net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 

i.support.ajax.i.ajaxTransport.send                        :     jquery-1.7.2.js:8241
i.extend.ajax                                              :      jquery-1.7.2.js:8241
```

My ajax function :

```
load = function (proxyPageName) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",  //I have try POST 
        url:  document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + proxyPageName + ".ashx" ,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (msg) {
            //when disabled chrome data compression 

        },
        error: function (xhr,options,error) {
            //when enable chrome data compression 
        }
    });
}
```

No error logged on the server.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Currently facing the same problem!

Comment: Sorry , NOT Solved ;,,,-(

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error recently after a server upgrade for 3 separate systems that all had the same behaviour.

I was seeing it for all users in Chrome, but only intermittently.

I was able to resolve it for all users by getting them to use Chrome's 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' refresh function for the site. (F12 for Chrome tools, right click on refresh button)

I suspect it related to something cached about the SSL certs being used.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running Windows 10? I've came across this problem a month ago and it's really tricky. First I've tried to fix Chrome by [disabling SPDY](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=978927), but it helped only for the Chrome, but on the other machines trying to access my IIS it was the same.

The actual problem is in the Windows 10 itself. Try [this trick with editing registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31975630/1208684). I hope it helps.