# Disabling HTTP/2 / SPDY in HTTP.SYS and IIS in Windows 10

Tags: iis, windows-10, http2, http.sys, wwsapi

When testing on Windows 10 we were seeing lots of browser incompatibilities that I hadn't seen before with earlier Windows versions. Some browsers would work, but others would report ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR. My quick search for this problem showed I was not alone.

My app uses WWSAPI and HTTP.SYS with HTTPS (TLS). Does anyone know how to disable SPDY / HTTP/2 in WWSAPI (which is using HTTP.SYS) on Windows 10?

I'd also love to get a full up-to-date Windows 10 list of registry settings for HTTP.SYS.

See below for my answer to this. Hope this helps others too.

Mark

Comment: This is a Q&A site. So if you have something that's on-topic for StackOverflow and hasn't already been answered, post a question where you formulate the problem that you initially had, and then post an answer to that question where you describe the solution.

Comment: Separate from just disabling HTTP/2, I'd like to understand why your WWSAPI is generating ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR in (I presume) Chrome.  Do you have a WWSAPI sample that shows that happening?

Comment: That is a Chromium error. We're currently seeing it in Opera, Chrome and Vivaldi. In our case because I think somebody is sending a signal we're providing http2 when we're not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable HTTP/2 on IIS of Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668151/how-to-disable-http-2-on-iis-of-windows-10)

Answer (score 21):

EDIT: disabling HTTP/2 will significantly slow down the speed of your website, this is not a permanent solution. The problem turned out to be caused by our webapp sending a wrong authentication header to the server.

To still disable HTTP/2, see below.

(OP gave a helpful answer, but in the question. I moved the answer):

> I did work around my HTTP/2 problem by configuring Windows 10 HTTP.SYS
>   in the registry to disable HTTP/2. Given that I didn't find info
>   anywhere, I thought I'd share my solution to that problem here too. I
>   would like to find a way of doing this through WWSAPI though.
>
> If I turned off SPDY support in the client browser, it would work but
>   I wanted to turn this off at the server side (HTTP.SYS on Windows 10)
>   so that it wouldn't negotiate HTTP/2 but would use the older more
>   compatible HTTP(S).
>
> Discovered two new registry settings for HTTP.SYS in:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
>
> - `EnableHttp2Tls` `REG_DWORD` `0`
> - `EnableHttp2Cleartext` `REG_DWORD` `0`
>
> Adding these values and setting both to 0 in Windows 10 resulted in
>   HTTP/2 / SPDY not being negotiated and my ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
>   problems went away without requiring browser configuration changes.
>   I'm not suggesting there is anything wrong with Windows 10 HTTP/2, the
>   problems may be with certain browsers.
>
> This may work for IIS too, but I don't use that so I haven't tried and
>   in any case there may be a better way to do this in IIS.
>
> Hope this helps others too.

I can confirm this helps for IIS too, but I had to **restart my computer**.

Comment: After setting the registry values and restarting my computer, I found out the the root cause of my SPDY issue was a connection reset coming from the server.

Comment: Although now I'm wondering, What if we want to shut off SPDY but not HTTP/2?

Comment: @EddieLoeffen Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Zero3 disabling SDPY on my computer forced connections to use HTTP/1.1 again. When I ran the same API call that was previously returning ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR, Chrome now told me the connection was reset. After fixing the bug causing a connection reset, I could re-enable SPDY without getting a protocol error.

Comment: @EddieLoeffen Aha! Thanks!

Comment: I, too, can confirm this works for Windows Server 2014 running IIS 10.0. It appears that HTTP/2, in conjunction with certain ciphers, causes modern browsers to throw a security exception. Disabling HTTP/2 fixes this issue by forcing IIS to use TLS 1.2 with the same ciphers. This is apparently more secure than the HTTP/2 option flag on.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off just SPDY and not HTTP2? @Jason

Comment: @EddieLoeffen what was the bug causing connection reset?