# IIS 10 - Chrome 44 ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY

Tags: google-chrome, iis, ssl, https

After upgrading to Windows 10, I am receiving the ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY in Google Chrome (Firefox 39 just doesn't load the page) when I attempt to access my machine over HTTPS. I have a GoDaddy signed certificate for my computer.

I've attempted disabling most of my encryption ciphers per https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#BadCipherSuites.

I've gone so far that I've disabled ciphers that are keeping me from RDPing to my desktop...and it still gives me an error!

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I just installed a new Exchange server with a GoDaddy cert and I have this issues on every browser but IE.  I can't exactly tell the entire world to disable something on their browser???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently you are not the only one having this issue: [Disabling HTTP/2 / SPDY in HTTP.SYS and IIS in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718533/disabling-spdy-http-2-in-http-sys-in-windows-10)

According to the error message this is a SPDY issue, so the certificate and the cipher suites are not the cause.

SPDY is a protocol allowing multiplexing HTTPS requests but it will be replaced by HTTP/2. As a temporary fix, you can apparently disable its support in you browser/registry/server.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same issue after my win 10 dev machine got updated twice recently (the updates took around 35-40 minutes to deploy each time) and after this i was not able to run my Visual studio 2015 web applications over Https on Chrome but was able to run on IE

- I tried out the registry method for disabling Http 2 as mentioned
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668151/how-to-disable-http-2-on-iis-of-windows-10), but this did not worked for me
- Then I came across the following solution: I downloaded [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) and
  selected "Cipher Suites" option and clicked Best Practices button, and applied
  it, My problem was gone and i can now run my web app over Https in Chrome just like before

Comment: Open IIS Crypto and clicked Best Practices button, it will apply the best practices and it works perfectly.

@Satbir thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Enable SSl" in your project properties under the Debug tab

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by removing the parameter "Strict´Transport-Security"  with value "max-age = 31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" from "HTTP Response Headers"