# MVC Redirect error in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, redirect

I've implemented mixed mode authentication in our MVC 5 application and everything seems to be working fine apart from one niggly problem.

When I browse to the site in Chrome the following page is displayed:

> This site can’t be reached
>   The web page at xxxx might be temporarily down or it may have moved
>   permanently to a new web address.

[ERR_UNEXPECTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkkGJ.jpg)

The main page is actually loaded, but I'm concerned that this might confuse users. The error doesn't appear in Firefox, IE or Edge.

I'm assuming it's down the redirects I'm performing during the login process, but I'm not sure why Chrome is showing the error.

The basic process is:

1. Forms authentication process checks if user is logged in
2. If authenticated, redirect to desired page (or default)
3. If no, redirect to signin action
4. Signin action then checks if single sign on is enabled, if it is then the user is redirected to an area of the site which can handle windows authentication. Otherwise they are redirected to the normal login page
5. User is then either authenticated using windows authentication, or redirect to login page

Just looking for any ideas as to why this error is only shown in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same behavior with chrome briefly displaying the above error before loading the page. I narrowed it down to a chrome issue while handling the http2->http1.1 downgrade caused by using windows authentication ([HTTP2 doesn't support windows authentication](https://blogs.iis.net/davidso/http2)).

I ended up working around the issue by [disabling http2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718533/disabling-http-2-spdy-in-http-sys-and-iis-in-windows-10) on the server. No real downside in my case since all the sites were behind windows authentication so the connection was always being downgrade to http1.1 anyways.

The following [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685741) has more detail.