# How to enable http2 with dotnet core version 2.2 using Http.Sys server?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, http2, http.sys

My machine/ project details:

1. Windows version is 10 Enterprise 1903 (OS build 18362.295)
2. Dotnet core version is 2.2.106, target framework version is 4.6.2

This is how the server is setup in code:

```
IWebHost localWebHost = new WebHostBuilder()
                               .UseHttpSys()
                               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                               .UseApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey)
                               .UseStartup<Startup>()
                               .UseUrls("http://+:8644")
                               .Build();
```

But calling with http version 2.0 still returns response with 1.1 (LinqPad script below):

```
async Task Main()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new Http2CustomHandler()))
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Restart();
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            // replacing uri with "https://www.google.com" returns http version 2.0
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8644/api/health", UriKind.Absolute)
        });
        response.RequestMessage.Version.Dump();
        response.Version.Dump();
        stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();

    }
}

public class Http2CustomHandler : WinHttpHandler
{
    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Version = new Version("2.0");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I get 2.0 from the `response.RequestMessage.Version` but 1.1 from `response.Version`. Replacing local uri with google's returns 2.0 in the response (so the code above is correct)

[HttpSysOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.httpsys.httpsysoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) does not have any parameter related to http2 either. Anyone know what else I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps this is reverse process to disabling? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718533/disabling-http-2-spdy-in-http-sys-and-iis-in-windows-10

Comment: Does it work using HTTPS? I'm not sure http.sys can even do http/2 without TLS application layer protocol negotiation (ALPN) involved upgrading the request to 2.0

Comment: Thanks Martin, but trying this on HTTPS on my deployed service (same code) running on Windows server 2019 (2016 is required for http2) also returns the same result, so I think something else is missing